# PlantUML export of coloured legend to SVG fails

Tags: svg, plantuml

I've followed the solution proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30999290/how-to-generate-a-legend-with-colors-in-plantuml?rq=1) successfully, but when trying to export the legend to SVG, the only thin visible is the last encoded color. Am I missing a closing instruction to avoid this?

Here you have a simplified example, try to export it to SVG and you will have a black square as a result. Export as PNG works fine.

```
@startuml

legend   
|= |= Colours | 
|<back:#F59175>   </back>| Pink | 
|<back:#FEFECE>   </back>| Yellow |
|<back:#000000>   </back>| Black | 

endlegend

@enduml
```

Solution to the problem (thanks to the comment of [GeekBoy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1309509/geekboy) ):

```
@startuml

legend   
|=   |= Colours | 
|<#F59175>| Pink | 
|<#FEFECE>| Yellow |
|<#000000>| Black | 

endlegend

@enduml
```

NB. dimension of the first column is defined by the first cell |=  |.

Comment: The problem is with the spaces in between the back tags. I had a similar issue with generating latex files. I just used \phantom to fill in dummy characters and applied the style manually.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I've tried to find how to implement a \phantom solution for plantuml and reviewing the documentation about creole, I've found a solution to my problem. <back> tag has to be avoided if blank, just add as many blanks as you need to dimension the column on the first row of the table, and use a color tag in each cell of the first column. Now export to SVG is fine. See edited question.

Answer (score 0):

The solution you posted above did not work for me (the color backgrounds only appear for yellow, and there was not much space in the cell). Here's the solution I found based on your original question:

```
@startuml

legend
|= |= Colours |
|<back:#F59175>   </back>| Pink |
|<back:#FEFECE>   </back>| Yellow |
|<back:#000000>   </back>| Black |
endlegend

@enduml
```

[image]

Here's the SVG version:

[image: SVG version]