Plant UML Multiple legend in Gantt View
How to add Multiple legend with different colors in Gantt Chart using Plant UML?
It's working for me, for one legned. It's taking the last line of code...
Is there a way to show, different parameter with different colros. Like "planned" "In progress" "Done" into grey, green blue color bars.
I have added below code :

legend{
Font Size
BackGround Color
}

legend
Test 1
end legend

legend{
Font Size
BackGround Color
}

legend
Test 2
end legend

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/44217931/1168342

Would this direct color encoding help?
legend
<font color=red>Warning:</font>
<font color=green>Ahoi!</font>
endlegend

